# How do I make this subquery factoring work with st_geometry predicates?

Tags: arcgis-10.4, oracle-spatial

I have the following SQL:

```sql
WITH w AS (select shape from schema.feature_class_polygon fcp where fcp.field = 123456)  
SELECT count(*)
FROM schema.feature_class_lines fcl
WHERE sde.st_intersects(w.shape, fcl.shape) = 1;
```

When I run the above SQL, I get the following error:

```sql
ORA-00904: "W"."SHAPE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: XX Column: YY
```

My question, how do I make the subquery factoring work with the st_geometry predicates?

The use of subquery factoring works in this ST_Geometry example, albeit not part of a WHERE clause:

```sql
WITH tmp AS (select sde.st_centroid(w.shape) shape from schema.feature_class_polygon w where w.field = 123456 )  
SELECT sde.st_x(tmp.shape), sde.st_y(tmp.shape) from tmp;
```

Comment: I guess I'm old-fashioned to use an explict `JOIN` to perform joins. Does this syntax work on non-spatial queries? What about other ADTs?